# How to have multiple (4) columns (or similar) with ListView.builder inside a row which all scroll together

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a type of timetable where each cell could have a different duration (height). To implement this there are 4 columns/listview/whatever which should all scroll together and each should (ideally) have a ListView.builder.

I've tried everything I can find on the internet to no avail. 
I'm still a beginner with Dart but I've tried every combination of ListView, Column, ListView.builder, Table, ... I could find and think of.

This is my current approach which works but refuses to allow me to use ListView.builder
If I replace a container with a ListView.builder then nothing is displayed

Here's a link to a gif of what I currently have, minus the ListView.builder part: [Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afggx.gif)

```dart
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
            height: header_height,
            child: Text(
              "Header spanning all 4 columns",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Table(
          children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 1",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 2",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 400,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 3",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 4",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Card(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
            height: header_height,
            child: Text(
              "Header spanning all 4 columns",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Table(
          children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 1",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 2",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 3",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 4",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Hi, How you want your layout to be like?

Comment: @meditat I've added a gif showing the desired outcome as I currently have it, just needs to use ListView.builder somehow

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Expanded Widget and documentation is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

For example

```
Expanded(child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text(
                        "Item 2",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help? I have the formatting and size working fine, the issue is that using ListView.builder instead of manually adding the cards displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right then This code will work for you.

```
ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehaviour(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        //Change it the count you want
        itemCount: Random().nextInt(10),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                  height: 36,
                  child: Text(
                    "Header spanning all 4 columns",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                  //change this too
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: Random().nextInt(9),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Table(
                      children: <TableRow>[
                        TableRow(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Item 1",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Item 2",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 400,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Item 3",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Item 4",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  })
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    )
```

And there is `MyBehaviour` class

```
class MyBehaviour extends ScrollBehavior {
 @override
 Widget buildViewportChrome(BuildContext context, Widget child,
  AxisDirection axisDirection) {
  return child;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Please excuse any syntax errors, I removed what I could to cut it down to just the necessary code).

I ended up figuring out that I could do this:

```dart
List<Widget> column_1 = [];
    var my_index;
    for (my_index = 0; my_index < my_list.length; my_index++) {
      //we need to do this otherwise it seems to -simultaneously- increment itself and be stuck at whatever.length...
      var tmp_index = my_index;
      column_1 .add(
        Card(
          child: Text("Item ${tmp_index}"),
        ),
      );
    }
```

And then use this to implement the generated lists of widgets:

```dart
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: Container(
            height: header_height,
            child: Text(
              "Header 1",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Table(
          children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  width: 50,
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(children: column_1 ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  width: 50,
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(children: column_2 ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  width: 50,
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(children: column_3 ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  width: 50,
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(children: column_4 ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Which has the added benefit of being able to place more full width header cards and tables underneath and the whole thing scrolls and acts like one huge table.